# SetDuration() class in android

Tags: animation, jquery-animate, android-animation

i have a problem with setDuration. for example i used this code:

```
 image.animate().alpha(1).set duration(200);
```

if in setting > developer option > animatordurationscale  is on x1,  this cod will be work.
but if the scale is x5 this cod will be work so slowly !
how i can turn off animate scale ?